# Is there a way to save last address that cause hardware fault or any while(1) in a COrtex M0+?

Tags: c, arm, stm32, cortex-m

Working on a STM32G0B0 (Cortex M0+), recently I have a problem with IWDG (independent watch dog).
Despite I never made it work properly as windowed one, it works decently as normal watchdog.
I set it quite hard at 10mS just to observe any glitches during development.
Never triggered, code works properly until today :))))

So I would like to know if my code execution was the problem (hard to believe)
Or just a bug hit me and landed to HarwareFault()
Finally, could be a non implemented vector, but shouldn't be unless a bug occured.

Similar to this thread
[How do I debug unexpected resets in a STM32 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806406/how-do-i-debug-unexpected-resets-in-a-stm32-device)

And this implementation for Cortex M3, M4
https://blog.frankvh.com/2011/12/07/cortex-m3-m4-hard-fault-handler/

I would like to know if there is a good way for M0+ to save at least address that caused jumping to HardwareFault.

Would be nice to save more for debug purposes.
I want to print that info after next reset.

Thanks for hints!

Note: I use bare metal C without any SDK except for definitions and ARM low level code.

**EDIT**
Following some guidance from here
https://community.silabs.com/s/article/debug-a-hardfault?language=en_US

There is a handler that they say is working on M0 but it isn't

```
void debugHardfault(uint32_t *sp)
{
    uint32_t r0  = sp[0];
    uint32_t r1  = sp[1];
    uint32_t r2  = sp[2];
    uint32_t r3  = sp[3];
    uint32_t r12 = sp[4];
    uint32_t lr  = sp[5];
    uint32_t pc  = sp[6];
    uint32_t psr = sp[7];
    while(1);
}

__attribute__( (naked) )
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    __asm volatile
    (
        "mrs r0, msp                                   \n"
        "mov r1, #4                                    \n"
        "mov r2, lr                                    \n"
        "tst r2, r1                                    \n"
        "beq jump_debugHardfault                       \n"
        "mrs r0, psp                                   \n"
        "jump_debugHardfault:                          \n"
        "ldr r1, debugHardfault_address                \n"
        "bx r1                                         \n"
        "debugHardfault_address: .word debugHardfault  \n"
    );
}


Error: selected processor does not support `mrs r0,msp' in Thumb mode
```

**EDIT2**
Found a handler for M0 at Segger
https://wiki.segger.com/Cortex-M_Fault

Implemented like this for M0

```
    .syntax unified
    .cpu cortex-m0plus
    .fpu softvfp
    .thumb

    .global HardFault_Handler
    .global NMI_Handler
    .global PendSV_Handler
    .global SVC_Handler


 HardFault_Handler:
 BusFault_Handler:
 UsageFault_Handler:
 MemManage_Handler:
 PendSV_Handler:
 SVC_Handler:
 NMI_Handler:

         ;// This version is for Cortex M0
         movs   R0, #4
         mov    R1, LR
         tst    R0, R1            ;// Check EXC_RETURN in Link register bit 2.
         bne    Uses_PSP
         mrs    R0, MSP           ;// Stacking was using MSP.
         b      Pass_StackPtr
 Uses_PSP:
         mrs    R0, PSP           ;// Stacking was using PSP.
 Pass_StackPtr:
         ldr    R2,=HardFaultHandler
         bx     R2                ;// Stack pointer passed through R0. 

         .end
```

IWDG (watchdog) was disabled and I triggered a HF manually like this

```
int _UnalignedAccess(void) {
  int r;
  volatile unsigned int* p;

  p = (unsigned int*)0x20000001; // not aligned
    r = *p;
  return r;
}
```

Collecting function

```
void HardFaultHandler(unsigned int* pStack) {

    HardFaultRegs.SavedRegs.r0 = pStack[0];  // Register R0
    HardFaultRegs.SavedRegs.r1 = pStack[1];  // Register R1
    HardFaultRegs.SavedRegs.r2 = pStack[2];  // Register R2
    HardFaultRegs.SavedRegs.r3 = pStack[3];  // Register R3
    HardFaultRegs.SavedRegs.r12 = pStack[4];  // Register R12
    HardFaultRegs.SavedRegs.lr = pStack[5];  // Link register LR
    HardFaultRegs.SavedRegs.pc = pStack[6];  // Program counter PC
    HardFaultRegs.SavedRegs.psr.byte = pStack[7];  // Program status word PSR
}
```

Still not working properly. Hardware fault is triggered but my function is not called at all. Instead, big crash and reset (no watchdog)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: One option would be to disable the IWDG, and use another timer that wraps around after 10ms (and generates an interrupt). Change your "reset the watchdog" to "reset the timer". Then put a breakpoint in the ISR for the timer.

Comment: It might also be worth checking what the reset cause was. The information is in the `RCC_CSR` register. There are HAL macros like `__HAL_RCC_GET_FLAG()` to abstract that. Most of my projects start by logging the reset cause on a UART, so I can detect flaky behaviour from the start.

Comment: Instead of searching on net install STM32CubeIDE and it has fault analyzer thich does all the hard job for you collecting the data from the stack and registers

Comment: @pmacfarlane Good point! IWDG doesn't have a handler but WWDG does! I will change to that one!

Comment: @0_________ Very good point, thanks! I already work in their IDE. The problem is that I want to do this on runtime

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve my initial log at runtime problem, I leave it open if someone have a good reply related to hardware fault saving.

But, thanks to @0___________ I found the bug & solved, using STM32's IDE "Fault Analyzer."

Here is what I found, pointer redirection to some junk structure due to loading from  other memory than expected.

```
/* Initially I had this
   But turned out that DRV.Tx.Cmd itself was NULL at some point
   So ->OnFailCmd happened to be valid, taken from address 0 + some struct offset 
   which was somewhere in Main Flash Memory
   
*/
if (DRV.Tx.Cmd->OnFailCmd) { // wrong way
    DRV.Tx.Cmd = DRV.Tx.Cmd->OnFailCmd; // wrongly loaded with junk, etc...
}


if (DRV.Tx.Cmd && DRV.Tx.Cmd->OnFailCmd) { // correct way
    DRV.Tx.Cmd = DRV.Tx.Cmd->OnFailCmd; 
}
```

Now the question is at runtime, this will be extremely hard to catch.
Execution loads a NULL struct, but members will still point to some junk due to MCU memory ( 0 + offset).

The real crash is unexpected:

- some jump to invalid address
- some load from invalid (missaligned) address (my case)

I need some kind of 2..3 levels log of PC jump.